# Why am I unable to use the Alfresco ADF identity user info component in my Angular project?

Tags: angular, alfresco

When attempting to use the ADF identity user info component in my existing Angular project, it's displaying nothing in the UI.

I added the ADF identity user info component to the HTML, but nothing is displaying on the screen. I used a class selector to check if it's within the container, but it still doesn't appear.

```
<div>
  <h1>Profile</h1>
  <adf-identity-user-info
    [bpmBackgroundImage]="'path/to/background-image.jpg'"
    [menuPositionX]="'after'"
    [menuPositionY]="'below'"
    [namePosition]="'right'"
    [showName]="true"
    class="container"

  ></adf-identity-user-info>
</div>
```

[image: component]
[image: nothing in UI]